# Does this series have a closed form? If so, what is it?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{x-1} \csc \left(\frac{(2 n+1)}{2 x} \pi\right)
$$

Where $x$ is a natural number.

This series emerged in trying to find a closed form expression for the following series:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \sum_{i=0}^{x-1} \frac{1}{2 xn+2i+1}
$$
Which is essentially the sum of reciprocals of odd numbers with $x$ consecutive pluses/minuses.
For example, with $x=1$, we get $1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5} \cdots=\frac{\pi}{4}$

With $x=2$, we get $1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{11}+…= \frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2}}$

I derived that for any $x$, the series is equivalent to $\frac{\pi}{4 x}$ times the aforementioned sum but was unable to find a simpler expression for the cosecant series.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In this forum, you need to show more than merely a statement of the problem.

Comment: Is the upper limit of the sum really a function of $x$?  Maybe $\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor $ instead of $x - 1$?

Comment: I assumed $x$ is a positive integer. But it does read strange. @SelrachDunbar

Comment: @GEdgar  why are you so scared of brevity?

Comment: You can see discussion of "missing context" in https://math.meta.stackexchange.com ... For example, we try to resist the tendency to become a "do my homework for me" site.

Comment: Yes, it has. Think first about Euler representation of trigonometric functions.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I tried this a bit using the Euler representation of cosecant but still found the expression difficult to simplify. Are there any other tips you could suggest to put me on the right track?

Comment: Please, post some working first. Look AT thé very first you received

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I spent some more time working with the Euler form and didn't really get anywhere. I tried using the symmetry of the series around pi/2 and the identity csc(x)=csc(pi-x) and didn’t get anywhere with that either.  I can also express the csc as summing up to pi/2 instead of pi, but I’m not sure how that helps. I’m just generally struggling to find a way to attack a solution. It seems like you know how to solve the problem, so if you could provide at least a specific approach or a first step, I would be very grateful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in a comment, you need to start with
$$\csc (t)=\frac 1{\sin(t)}=\frac {2i}{e^{it}-e^{-it}}=\frac {2i\,e^{it}}{1-e^{-2it}}$$

Now, you must consider the definition of the q-digamma function and its extension to the q-polygamma function (have a look [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html) for example) and in particular to their relation to Lambert series.

This makes that, according to the given definitions and above notations, if
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^m \csc(k\, t+a)$$
$$i \,\log \left(e^{-i t}\right)\, S=\left(\psi _{e^{-i t}}^{(0)}\left(m+1-\frac{\log \left(e^{i
   a}\right)}{\log \left(e^{-i t}\right)}\right)-\psi _{e^{-i
   t}}^{(0)}\left(-\frac{\log \left(e^{i a}\right)}{\log
   \left(e^{-i t}\right)}\right)\right)-$$ $$\left(\psi _{e^{-i t}}^{(0)}\left(m+1-\frac{\log \left(-e^{i
   a}\right)}{\log \left(e^{-i t}\right)}\right)-\psi _{e^{-i
   t}}^{(0)}\left(-\frac{\log \left(-e^{i a}\right)}{\log
   \left(e^{-i t}\right)}\right) \right)$$

Just change the notation to find the expression for your problem
$$S_x=\sum_{n=0}^{x-1} \csc \left(n\,\frac{\pi }{x}+\frac{\pi }{2 x}\right)$$

For the first values of $x$, it is quite simple
$$\left\{1,2 \sqrt{2},5,4 \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}},1+4 \sqrt{5},2
   \left(\sqrt{2}+2 \sqrt{6}\right)\right\}$$ but after $x=6$, problems because of the angles.

You must take care that the calculation of the q-polygamma function is quite expensive in term of resources.

Now, compare to the so simple continuous case
$$T_x=\int_{0}^{x-1} \csc \left(n\,\frac{\pi }{x}+\frac{\pi }{2 x}\right)\,dn=\frac{2 x}{\pi }\,\log \left(\cot \left(\frac{\pi }{4 x}\right)\right)$$

$S_x$ is, as usual, very hightly coreelated to $T_x$ (if you perform a linear regression with no intercept, $R^2=0.999736$) and the simple $T_x$ really shows all the trends.

Comment: Thank you for writing a more in-depth answer, but I’m afraid I’m still confused. Shouldn’t $csc (t)$ be equal to $\frac{2 i e^{it}}{e^{2 it}-1} \\$ not
$ \frac{2 ie^{it}}{1-e^{-2 i t}}$ as you wrote? Also, could you go into more depth on how you derived the expression with the q-polygamma function? This is my first exposure to either the q-polygamma function or Lambert series, so I would appreciate it if you were quite specific as to which identities you used. Thank you so much for your help!